# Using CVPixelBuffer is only way to create CAMetalTexture(MTLTexture)?

Tags: swift, graphics, metal

In CVPixelBuffer, is there a way to create a texture by simply using a pointer other than copyMemory from the base address of the yuv data pointer to the y, u, v plane?

The method to create a texture by copyMemory takes about 0.5ms, but I want to get a better speed.

I know that OpenGL and DirextX have a way to get faster speeds by passing a pointer and having the GPU generate the texture.

Please tell me any method for faster texture creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

You can use a `CVMetalTextureCache` to create textures from `CVPixelBuffers`.

You need to create a texture cache first using [`CVMetalTextureCacheCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456774-cvmetaltexturecachecreate) and use it in [`CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456754-cvmetaltexturecachecreatetexture) to create the texture (scroll down on the docu page for examples).
You can (and should) create the texture cache once with the appropriate settings and re-use it every time you need to create a texture.

Comment: Is there any way to make YUV pixel data into MTLTexture without using CVMetalTextureCacheCreate and CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage??


I don't want to use time to copy memory to y, u, v plane of CVPixelBuffer from base address of YUV pixel data.


This is because time management is sensitive to output multiple camera images on the screen.

Comment: `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` will not copy the data. It will create a texture with the same underlying buffer memory, so it should be fast.

Comment: When creating yTexture, it takes about 0.5ms, and the subsequent creation of u and vTexture is very insignificant at 0.00~ms.

1. Is yTexture taking longer because it uses cache for the first time?

2. My goal is to output 30 ips 64 camera images at 60hz, but it takes more than 0.5ms for texture creation, and 1.5ms or more if i add render environment settings. In this situation, it seems difficult to achieve that goal.